# Why can't I use `nopython=True` with `numba.guvectorize` on this function?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

If I try to use `nopython=True` with `numba.guvectorize` on the following function, I get

```
NotImplementedError: Don't know how to create implicit output array with 'A'
layout. --%<-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The documentation isn't clear on the proper way to use `nopython=True` with `numba.guvectorize`.  I've looked at the annotated output generated by `numba --annotate-html`, and I think the reason has something to do with the way `tmp` is initialized. I am using

- python = 3.4.1.final.0 (Anaconda)
- numpy = 1.9.3
- numba = 0.21.0
- llvmpy = 0.12.7

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.guvectorize(['(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])'], '(),(),(n),() -> (n)')
def _gpcm(theta, a, thresh, D, res):

    tmp = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    tmp[0] = a *  D * (theta - thresh[0])
    bot = 0

    for j in range(1, thresh.shape[0]):
        if not np.isnan(thresh[j]):
            tmp[j] = tmp[j - 1] + a * D * (theta - thresh[j])

    for j in range(thresh.shape[0]):
        if not np.isnan(thresh[j]):
            tmp[j] = np.exp(tmp[j])
            bot += tmp[j]

    for j in range(thresh.shape[0]):
        if not np.isnan(thresh[j]):
            res[j] = tmp[j] / bot
        else:
            res[j] = 0
```

Comment: does guvectorize take nopython as a param?  I only see it used as a jit param.

Comment: well, thanks for making me look at the documentation again.  Yes, it does, and in trying to find where it says it in numba's documentation I found my problem has to do with how I'm accessing the scalars values ... I made a minor edit, and it compiles just fine with nopython=True ... I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: can you post the link to the docs you're referencing?  Also yea, I see it now, you would need to access scalars as arrays, `theta[0]`.

Comment: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html#the-guvectorize-decorator), in reference to `guvectorize`

> The concrete signature does not allow for scalar values, even though
>   the layout may mention them. In this example, the second argument is
>   declared as int64[:], not int64. This is why it must be dereferenced
>   by fetching y[0].

So, I just had to change how I was accessing my scalars. Changing my original function to

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.guvectorize(['(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])'], '(),(),(n),() -> (n)', nopython=True)
def _gpcm(theta, a, thresh, D, res):

    tmp = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    tmp[0] = a[0] *  D[0] * (theta[0] - thresh[0])
    bot = 0

    for j in range(1, thresh.shape[0]):
        if not np.isnan(thresh[j]):
            tmp[j] = tmp[j - 1] + a[0] * D[0] * (theta[0] - thresh[j])

    for j in range(thresh.shape[0]):
        if not np.isnan(thresh[j]):
            tmp[j] = np.exp(tmp[j])
            bot += tmp[j]

    for j in range(thresh.shape[0]):
        if not np.isnan(thresh[j]):
            res[j] = tmp[j] / bot
        else:
            res[j] = 0
```

Solved the problem.